# The smallest positive period of the function $\sin{(k\cos{x})}$

Tags: functions

> Let $$f(x)=\sin{(k\cos{x})},k>0$$
> Find the minimum of $T>0$, such
> $$f(x+T)=f(x), \ \forall x\in R$$

I have know $$f(x+2\pi)=\sin{(k\cos(x+2\pi))}=f(x)$$
maybe $T_{min}=2\pi$?, I can't proof why $2\pi$ is smallest? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the minimum period of $f$. Since the period of $\sin(x)$ is $2\pi$, it must be true that

$$k\cos(x+T)=k\cos(x)+2\pi n\\
\implies \cos(x+T)=\cos(x)+\frac{2\pi n}{k}$$

for some $n \in \Bbb{Z}$.  The range of $k\cos(x+T)$ is $[-1,1]$. The range of $\cos(x)+\frac{2\pi n}{k}$ is $\big[-1+\frac{2\pi n}{k}, 1+\frac{2\pi n}{k}\big]$.  These can only be equal if $n=0$.  Hence,

$$\cos(x+T)=\cos(x)$$

But we know the minimum period of $\cos(x)$ is $2\pi$, so $T=2\pi$.

Comment: why only be equality $n=0?$

Comment: @communnites Otherwise, $\cos(x+T)$ and $\cos(x)+\frac{2\pi n}{k}$ have a different range, so they cannot be equal.

Comment: no,$\dfrac{2\pi n}{k}$ can any real numbers

Comment: @communnites No. Assume $n>0$. Then for $x=0$, $\cos(x)+\frac{2\pi n}{k}=1+\frac{2\pi n}{k}>1$. But $\cos(x+T)=\cos(T)\leq 1$. Thus, they cannot be equal. Similarly, if $n<0$, we get a contradiction by setting $x=\pi$.

Comment: @greelious So how would one prove that $T_{min}=2\pi$?, because it is not realized or true that $\cos(x+T)=\cos(x)+\frac{2\pi n}{ k}$.

Answer (score -2):

If
$f(x)=\sin(k\cos(x))
$
then
$f(x+2\pi)
=\sin(k\cos(x+2\pi))
=\sin(k\cos(x))
=f(x)
$
since
$\cos(x+2\pi)
=\cos(x)
$.

Comment: He's asking how do you know that there isn't a smaller period than $2\pi$

Comment: Yes,I can't proof  why  $2\pi$ is smallest?